# "User was removed" : What happens to the question?

Tags: support, deleted-users

I lost 15 rep points because an [User was removed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed).

This is part of the rules and I respect this.

However, by the sake of curiosity, **I would like to know which and how questions and answers were impacted by an user removal**.

I cannot afford to browse my answers one by one and to check if the question comes from a removed user.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lost reputation due to a user removal this means that the post you got reputation for was also removed. It's therefore impossible to search for (without mod privileges) on the site and it will no longer appear in the Data Explorer.

Your only option is to click on the "deleted recent answers" link at the bottom of the Answers tab in your user profile, and see if it's there.

Comment: But a user removal wouldn't affect any other posts than the ones belonging to the deleted user.

Comment: Yes, but if that was a question it'll delete the answer @Bolt.

Comment: deleted recent questions/answers will not show posts if those deleted posts were from 2012....

Comment: @Ben: Oh, right.

Comment: My answer is not in the "show recent...". I can only aee an answer I deleted by myself some time ago.I think deleting an user plus his content is a bit rough and I intend to put a feature request: question and answers I am involved in are important to me regardless the reputation.

Comment: Oh I missed the duplicate. Then if the question had a negative score it is not that important then. I am ok with this.

Comment: @Larry FWIW in [related discussion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/what-roomba-script-went-after-this-question#comment18430_6821) it was recommended to consider editing the question you answer. If your edit improves it enough to get out of negative score, it would stay and you would keep the rep